# Why don't we have a share link?

Tags: feature-request

Posts don't have the usual *share* link at the bottom. Why? Is this a private beta "feature".

Previously I wrote a meta post and wanted to refer to an answer but there is no *share* button to simpify this.

Comment: I'm half in favor of showing the share link without the share functionality and call it 'permalink' in private beta, for just this reason.

Answer (score 6):

Actually that is by design. We're currently in private beta, so uncommitted users wouldn't be able to see it.

Source: [Sharing Links On Non-Public Beta Sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76768/169573)

Comment: I completely agree with your answer, but just to add, if you send a private beta invite by email to a user from another site that you want to share SR with, you can copy and paste the question or answer from the address bar for them to click on (after they accept the email invite) and they'll be able to view it.